# Java : multiply 2 elements from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I output the total cost of the products in the program? The output is always 0 with my program.

I have an arrayList and the type is an object called Product;

```
static ArrayList<Product> productArray = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

The product constructor is;

```
public Product(String productName, String productLink, double purchasePrice, String purchaseDate,
        String repurchaseDate, int quantity) {
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productLink = productLink;
    this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
    this.repurchaseDate = repurchaseDate;
}
```

I'm trying to loop through the arraylist, to out put the total cost of the products. The total cost of the products is the quantity*thePurchasePrice. The method is;

```
public static void totalSpend() {
    
    double productCost = 0, totalCost = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < productArray.size(); i++) {
        
        productCost = ((double)productArray.get(i).getQuantity()) * ((double)productArray.get(i).getPurchasePrice());
        
        System.out.println("\nThe "+productArray.get(i).getProductName()+" costs £"+productArray.get(i).getPurchasePrice());
        
        totalCost+= productCost;
        
    }
    
    System.out.println("\nThe total cost is £"+totalCost);

}//methodEnd
```

I've tried casting productCost to a double and int, tried moving the productCost and totalCost to within the loop.

Comment: Hint: dissect your code step by step. When you don't know, what your code is doing: then PRINT more. Meaning: fetch the quantity into a local variable. Print that variable. Fetch the price into a local variable, print that. Most likely, one of those things is always 0, does * 0 gives 0, thus 0+0 stays 0.

Comment: Beyond that, see [mcve]. You only gave us fragments of your code. Read that link, then [edit] your question and the missing parts.

Comment: And then: assument that your productArray is actually a `List<Product>` ... then just iterate it using `for (Product p : productArray)` ... there is no need to use index-based for looping for lists. And then: use meaningful names: no sense in calling a LIST of products a productArray. Just call it products!

Comment: You don't need to do any casting I believe. Can you please check `productArray` has elements which contains non-zero value of `quantity` & `purchasePrice`

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, my code now uses the {for (Product p : productArray)} format. Will prepare a minimal reproducible example next time. The one I prepared was working, and have been troubleshooting. The answer from FreemanB solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, you should post more of the code to see how it ties together, but based on what you have here, I think I see the problem. The constructor for Product has a parameter for quantity, but you don't actually save that value anywhere in the constructor.( this.quantity = quantity ) Assuming that the getQuantity() returns an int stored somewhere in the Product class, it will likely just be returning the default int value of zero, resulting in the product cost always being zero no matter what else you do.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you! I added quantity later on, after the constructor, and forgot to add it. Noted on the additional code, will do next time. I prepared a minimal version as suggested by @GhostCat, but the minimal version was working and I've been trying to trouble shoot the difference :-D

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass an array to a method?
It looks like your method is working with an array without data. Initialize the array with Product objects and pass it to the method

Try:
`public static void totalSpend(ArrayList<Product> productArray){`

Comment: This is not answering the question ...because the question itself is unclear. So please don't misuse the answer feature to send vague guesses or to ask for clarification.